# Open AI api, python, function calls

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, openai-api

I'm trying to make chat bot for a website. I added sending email function as available function for the model. Though with promp "if user asks to send email say that you can do it if name, email, and message are provided, message can be simple, but user must provide all the data before you send email, if user does not tell any from name, email, and message do not send email", it answers as expected, but there is a problem. When I gave the model email and message without name it told me that i need to provide name. but at the same time function call worded and send email without name. Why this happened and how do function calls work ?

i added excpetions for sending email function. So it checks if name in 'User', 'user', 'Unknown', 'unknown', 'No name', 'noname', 'Noname' etc. But more try chat with the model more new values appear as something that is send as name but not a an appropriate value for name. But even with when model asks for name and give it no name it use it as name and sends email

```
def send_emails(name, message, email_of_customer):
    subject_technical = 'Programming Order Alert'
    subject_customer = 'Your Order Confirmation'
    from_email = 'my email'
    technical_email = ['my email']
    customer_email = [email_of_customer]
    
    technical_message = f'New programming order received from {name}, email {email_of_customer}. Message: {message}'
    
    context = {'name': name}
    html_content = render_to_string('html/sent.html', context)
    text_content = strip_tags(html_content) 
    
    email_to_customer = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject_customer, text_content, from_email, customer_email)
    email_to_customer.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")

    mails = ['example@gmail.com', 'my email', f'{name}example@gmail.com']
    names = ['User', 'user', 'Unknown', 'unknown', 'No name', 'noname', 'Noname',
    'Noname'
    ]


    try:
        if name not in names and customer_email not in mails:
            email_to_customer.send()
            send_mail(subject_technical, technical_message, from_email, technical_email)
            return 'Email sent successfully'
        else:
            return 'need more data'
    except Exception as e:
        return 'Sorry, something went wrong with sending the HTML email to the customer.'




def generate_response(user_question, prev_question=None):
    tools = [
        {
            "type": "function",
            "function": {
                "name": "send_emails",
                "description": "send techinical email andreyabout new orders",
                "parameters": add_func_properties
            },
        },
    ]

    messages = []

    if not prev_question:
        messages.append(
                {
                    "role": "assistant",
                    "content": initial_role,
                }
            )

    else:
        messages.extend(
            prev_question
            )

    messages.append(
            {"role": "user", "content": user_question}
            )
            
    try:
        response = client.chat.completions.create(
            model="gpt-4",
            messages=messages,
            tools=tools,
            tool_choice='auto',
        )

        response_message = response.choices[0].message
        tool_calls = response_message.tool_calls

        if tool_calls:
            available_functions = {
                "send_emails": send_emails,
            }

            messages.append(response_message)

            for tool_call in tool_calls:
                function_name = tool_call.function.name
                function_to_call = available_functions[function_name]
                function_args = json.loads(tool_call.function.arguments)
                if function_name == "send_emails":
                    function_response = function_to_call(
                        name=function_args.get("name"),
                        message=function_args.get("message"),
                        email_of_customer=function_args.get("email_of_customer")
                    )

            messages.append(
                {
                    "tool_call_id": tool_call.id,
                    "role": "tool",
                    "name": function_name,
                    "content": f'the response:{function_response}',
                }
            )

            follow_up_response = client.chat.completions.create(
            model="gpt-4",
            messages=messages,
        )
            return follow_up_response.choices[0].message.content

        return response.choices[0].message.content
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error generating response: {e}")
        return f"I'm sorry, I couldn't process your request right now. the error {e}"
```